# In Java web app, how to add common-codec 1.6 although AWS SDK uses 1.3 internally

Tags: java, jar, amazon-web-services, classpath

I'm building a Java web app using Amazon SDK for java.
The SDK uses 3rd party Apache common-codec 1.3.
I've added common-codec 1.6 to the project (I need it) but it still "finds" the one from the SDK first.
What should be done in scenarios such as this.
I can remove the 1.3 from the SDK but I guess it's bad practice to just upgrade a library that Amazon uses "internally".

Comment: When you say : "it still "finds" the one from the SDK first" you mean in Eclipse? or at runtime?

Comment: I mean Eclipse. I am trying to use a function that was introduced in 1.6 and it gives me an error saying it is available (because it takes the class from 1.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the project->properties->java build path->Order and Export tab, choose your SDK and move it up in the order.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Will that ensure the classloader will load the class from 1.6 before?

Comment: This is just for compilation time, not sure how it'll behave at runtime.